# getting ODBC Sql Sever Driver DBNETLIB Invalid Connection error

Tags: vb.net

i am working on vb.net windows application, it included vb6 reporting application exe also,for this application i am using SQL Server,In  my working system it is working good. I have installed EXE in client system ,Some times in some systems i am getting this error like :

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB] Invalid connection
```

any one please give me the suggestion on what i have to do.